# Diff operator question for QM

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If I have a substitution like
$u=\frac{1}{a}x$,
how do I get this?
$$\frac{d}{du}\equiv a\frac{d}{dx}$$

Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=au,$ then $\color{green}{\dfrac{dx}{du}=a},$ so, by the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), $\dfrac{df}{du}=\dfrac{df}{dx}\color{green}{\dfrac{dx}{du}}=\color{green}a\dfrac{df}{dx}$.